# How to add the main style.css to my index.php?

Tags: themes, css, wp-enqueue-style

I'm creating for the first time a theme **from scratch**.

> It's not a child theme

In theme's `function.php` file I'm doing

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {

  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri()); 
});
```

But the `style.css` file is not included  in the served html.

Is there something I must do to 'force' inclusion of my theme's CSSes ?

In the `index.php` I tried to print `get_stylesheet_uri()` and I got the full URL of my css: `http://my.domain.it/wp-content/themes/real/style.css`

For reference, this is my theme's `index.php`

```
<!-- Inizio di INDEX.PHP -->

<?php 
  get_header();
?>

<!-- Index.php, dopo get_header(); !-->

<DIV id="container">

  <div id="row1">
    Riga 1
  </div>

  <div id="row2">
    Riga 2
  </div>

</DIV> <?php //  id="main_container" ?>

<!-- Index.php, prima di get_footer(); !-->

<?php 
  get_footer();
?>

<!-- Fine di INDEX.PHP -->
```

I'm calling `get_header()` and my header file is included

This is Header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title>
      <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
    </title>

    <meta name="description" content=" <?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>  ">

  </head>
  <body>

<!-- Fine di HEADER.PHP -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found:

As stated here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head.

> Put this template tag immediately before  tag in a theme template (ex. header.php, index.php).

So I added

```
<?php wp_head() ?>
```

just before `</HEAD` and now it works.

Comment: ohh, so you were not including header in your page?

Comment: I was including my headers, but not WP's header :) . It's my first steps with a scratch theme. It's not very well documented this steps, or I've not seen.

Answer (score -1):

let's try this way:

```
<?php
//
// Recommended way to include parent theme styles.
//  (Please see http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme)
//  

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array('parent-style')
    );
}
```

Comment: It's a simplet CODE styling difference. I use anonymous function. You not. The code is the same. Also, i'm not doing a child theme. I started from scratch. From empty index.php and empty style.css. I added some other hooks to my functions.php file and all of theme are working well. Just this is not working.

Answer (score -1):

use `<?php wp_head() ?>` before `</head>` in header.php and then use this codes in function.php :

```
function my_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style(  'style', get_stylesheet_uri()); 
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_style' );
```